# Sqflite support for aliases

Tags: sqlite, sqflite, floor, moor

Does SQFLite supports aliases like SQLite database?

e.g

```
column_name AS alias_name
```

want to use nested select query and give nested select query value to specific field

Answer (score 0):

Yes. sqflite does not do any SQL parsing and uses SQLite